# Imposing units of measure on Java `int` at compile-time?

Tags: java, primitive, units-of-measurement

Is there a way to impose the concept of "units of measure" on a Java `int` at compile-time, but not use object references at runtime?

In Java code, I would like to protect developers from mixing units of measure when combining primitive data types, such as in this mistake ...

```
int duration1 = 17;    // Number of **seconds**.
int duration2 = 42;    // Number of **minutes**.
int total = duration1 + duration2;    // <== MISTAKE: Mixed units of measure!
```

The mistake in the last line is that the developer is adding seconds to minutes.  Because everything is an `int`, the Java compiler will not complain about this, so the mistake can only be caught by a clever unit test or by a customer (*shudder*).

**Is there a way for the compiler to reject this mistake?**

Just to be clear, I am not looking for run-time unit conversion -- I want compile-time unit checking.

For example, if it were possible to derive from `int` (*but it is not possible*), I could imagine errant code like this ...

```
DurationSec duration1 = 17;      // Number of seconds.
DurationMin duration2 = 42;      // Number of minutes.
DurationSec total = duration1 + duration2;    // <== COMPILE ERROR!
```

In the above code, the compiler would complain about the third line, because there is no automatic conversion between classes DurationSec and DurationMin, even though both classes are based upon `int`.

The third line might be correctly written (*in my imagination*) as ...

```
DurationSec total = duration1 + (DurationSec) (60 * (int) duration2);  // OK
```

Yes, I realize that this could be done with classes, but I need the performance of the `int` native data type, so I do not want to introduce the overhead of object references.  I just want to wrap `int` in thin, compile-time classes.

**Any ideas?**

Is there an obscure, new feature in Java that can do this compile-time checking, while adding no (*or trivial*) overhead to the code and runtime?

Is there a way to tell Java to optimize-out all the object overhead, and handle just the `int`?

Comment: Using classes may not be as bad as you think in terms of performance.

Comment: It is not possible to do with in Java, your only option is to have good unit tests.  If this feature is very important to you consider a different language that does have this.  Also, I would try it with object wrappers and test performance to see if you really do need to use primitive values.  If there's no noticeable difference, I'd go with the extra type safety over saving a few microseconds.

Comment: Is this premature optmization or have you profiled something like `java.time.Duration` and determined that the performance is inadequate for you?

Comment: I understand your question, but frankly if you need this, your developers aren't great. The line "int total = durationInSec + durationInMin" just doesn't make any sense, pure and simple. This is not a language limitation. If you're worried about this, then why not worry about all the other ints you have in your project? Would you like to have a feature in Java that allows you to create a separate kind of int for every different possible integer you can have? It would be complete confusion.

Comment: In my situation, I see this as a compile-time problem, so I'm looking for a pure compile-time solution.  Where I come from, _we count CPU cycles_, so if it has any run-time impact, I probably can't make it happen.  _Sigh_
 
Regardless, I would be amiss to not ask for your advice, _non?_

Comment: @puhlen:  Yes, better unit tests is always a good idea.  _Amen._